# Forcing WiFi connection programmatically on iOs with Unity

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, unity-game-engine, wifi

I have an application that is used on a specific situation :

- The application is ran on an iPad mini 4 using iOS 9.
- Before the application startup the iPad mini is connected to a WiFi network.
- When using the application the user will move, and will therefore lose the WiFi signal and be disconnected.
- If the user returns near the WiFi router after losing the signal for more than ~30 minutes, it does not reconnect directly to the WiFi network (connecting to the network usually takes up to another 30 minutes). That is not the desired behaviour, and I would like for my application to make the iPad reconnect instantly to the same WiFi network (maybe with a function call).
- If the user returns near the WiFi router after losing the signal for less than ~30 minutes, the iPad will actually reconnect on its own while the application is runnning.

Is there a way to reconnect programmatically to a known WiFi network using Unity function ?

NB : If the user minimize the application when near the router, it will reconnect to the WiFi network, as expected.

NB2 : [UIRequiresPersistentWiFi](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW12) is set to true.

Comment: fascinating, I thought it would connect immediately.  Do you mean it **starts using cellular data** ??

Comment: This iPad Mini 4 is not connected to the cellular network. Therefore when it loses the WiFi connection, it doesn't have an internet access anymore.

Comment: is this just with "your" iPadMini4, or have you tested with others?  do you have a really old WiFi router?  I have an iPad mini and it reconnects within a second.  could you just try it on another router, at the office or at friends?

Comment: same here. the whole purpose of operating system is to let developers not  to worry about small things like this XD

Comment: It happens with different WiFi router (I've tested it on two Apple Airport and a Livebox Play), and unfortunately the problem isn't tied to my iPad Mini 4. I'm going to add some precision on my first message.

Comment: fascinating question !